# Possible value for $f(\frac{1}{2})$ for some function $f:\mathbb{D}\to\mathbb{D}$

Tags: complex-analysis

> **Q.20.**<sup>[source)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/148bH.jpg)</sup> Let $\mathbb{D} = \{z \in \mathbb{C} : \left| z \right| < 1\}$ be the open unit disc and let $f : \mathbb{D} \to \mathbb{D}$ be a holomorphic function. Suppose that $f(0) = 0$ and $f^\prime(0) = 0$. Which of the followings are possible values of $f\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$?
>
> 1. $1/4$
> 2. $-1/4$
> 3. $1/3$
> 4. $-1/3$

Here I know that 1, 2 are correct if we choose $f(z)=z^2$ and $f(z)=-z^2$. Please give some hint for options 3 and 4.

Comment: Hint: apply [maximum modulus principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_modulus_principle) to $\frac{f(z)}{z^2}$

Comment: @clark $f$ maps $\mathbb{D}\to\mathbb{D}$

Comment: @Caffeine, is right.

Comment: Please use MathJax to format your question. It greatly helps the question visible to various search engines and hence is crucial for maintaining this community as a repository of mathematical knowledge. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773). You may also want to give [this posting](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/9340) a read to learn how to ask a good question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answers $3$ and $4$ are not correct.

Since $\;f(0)=f^\prime(0)=0\;,\;$ there exists a holomorphic function $\;g:\mathbb{D}\to\mathbb{C}\;$ such that

$f(z)=z^2g(z)\quad\forall\;z\in\mathbb{D}\;.$

If $\;|z|=r<1\;,\;$ then $\;|g(z)|=\dfrac{|f(z)|}{|z|^2}<\dfrac{1}{r^2}\;,$

and, by the maximum modulus principle, it follows that

$|g(z)|<\dfrac{1}{r^2}\quad$ for all $\;z\in\mathbb{C}\;$ such that $\;|z|\le r<1\;.$

As $\;r\to1\;,\;$ we get that

$|g(z)|\le1\;$ for all $\;z\in\mathbb{C}\;$ such that $\;|z|<1\;,$

hence,

$|f(z)|=|z|^2|g(z)|\le|z|^2\;$ for all $\;z\in\mathbb{C}\land|z|<1\;,$

consequently,

$\left|f\left(\frac12\right)\right|\le\frac14\;.$

Comment: Why have you downvoted me? Which mistakes are there?

Comment: I downvoted your original, incorrect answer.

Comment: But now it is fine, right

Comment: @J.Doe yes, the current version is correct (and I upvoted it too).